# Conditioned formatting of a cell in relation to another cell

Tags: google-sheets

Cell B1 should be colored red if cell A1 contains a certain string.

I thing this should be possible but I don't succed.

Thank you in advance for your answer!

Comment: Hi and welcome to WebApps. The problem that you describe is solved by using the feature called `Conditional Formatting`. To learn about this feature, you might start by reading the documentation: [Use conditional formatting rules in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?hl=en). If you have a specific question after reading this, would please explain what you have tried to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Highlight Column B and go to Format -> Conditional formatting -> Custom formula and put `=A:A="your-string-here"`

This works if you have one string and need one color for highlighting. If you have multiple strings, you could do `=OR(A:A="your-string-here",A:A="your-other-string-here")`. If you need another color, just make and apply a new conditional rule on your range.